# + Regular Expression not working in sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

Team,

I have a file with data as mention below.

```
[root@ip-12-32-8-15 ~]# cat dbbackup

(555)555-1212

(555)555-1213
```

## Expected Output:

```
First: (555) Second: 555- Third: 1212

First: (555) Second: 555- Third: 1213
```

I am using sed its not working .

```
sed -n -e 's/\([0-9]+)\)\([0-9]+-\)\([0-9]+\)/First: \1 Second: \2 Third: \3/p' dbbackup
```

Please Let me know how to achieve the above mention output.

Comment: Btw.: with awk: `echo '(555)555-1212' | awk -F '[()-]' '{print "First: " $2 " Second: " $3 " Third: " $4}'`

Comment: In which way "its not working"?

Comment: Count `(` and `)` in your sed command.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/$/\nfirst:second:third:fourth:\n/;:a;s/^([(0-9]+[)-]?)([^\n]*\n)([^:]*:)(.*)/\2\4 \3 \1/;ta;s/\n.*\n //' file
```

This method matches the numbers at the front of the string with strings appended to the end of the line and then appends them to end of the introduced line. Eventually there are no more numbers to remove and then the introduced newlines/final space are deleted, leaving the required string.

N.B. Additional strings may be appended for further numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In GNU awk (`FIELDWIDTHS`), no regex:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="5 4 4"}{print "First:",$1,"Second:",$2,"Third:",$3}' file
First: (555) Second: 555- Third: 1212
First: (555) Second: 555- Third: 1213
```

Another in sed:

```
$ sed 's/^/First: /1;s/./& Second: /12;s/./& Third: /25' file
First: (555) Second: 555- Third: 1212
First: (555) Second: 555- Third: 1213
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. My requirement need to use only sed with Regex

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the opening parenthesis before the first field. But this is not the reason it doesn't work.
It doesn't work because `sed` does not know `+`. Use `*` instead:

```
sed -n -e 's/\(([0-9]*)\)\([0-9]*-\)\([0-9]*\)/First: \1 Second: \2 Third: \3/p'
```

Comment: wrong: `sed` do know `+` regex command. It simply needs to be escaped `\+` or being used with `-r` option

Comment: Then how to use (+) in sed regular expression

Comment: @oliv Although `\+` is a common extension, [POSIX BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03) doesn't have `\+` as a defined quantifier. But it's right too that a one-liner sed script that executes multiple commands like current answer is not portable.

Comment: Not all versions of `sed` accept extended regular expressions. The one that ships with `macOS`, for exemple, doesn't know them.

Comment: @revo I agree with your remark, but I disagree with the sentence _It doesn't work because sed does not know +_ in this answer. I don't think there are many linux systems that have a `sed` that is strictly posix compliant unless the option `--posix` is set.

Comment: @oliv I think it's better to write your own answer (with whatever options you want to pass to `sed`) than downvoting an answer just because you disagree with a sentence it contains. Hover on the downvote button and you'll see the reason to downvote an answer is "This answer is not useful" and not "I don't agree with it". This answer works. Maybe it is not useful to you but it could be useful to somebody else.